# How to create several buffers around points of a simple feature in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, buffer, r-sf

I have sample data representing 2 points (sf). I want to create buffers with the width 2, 1 and 0.5. My approach is the below. Is there any way to do this in more efficient way? How can I wrap this process up in a loop?

```
library(sf)

g = st_sfc(c(st_point(1:2),st_point(3:2)))

g.2 <- st_buffer(g,2)
g.1 <- st_buffer(g,1)
g.05 <- st_buffer(g,0.5)

plot(st_geometry(g.2))
plot(st_geometry(g.1), add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(g.05), add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(g), add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following. I created a loop with `map()` in the purrr package and created three objects in a list. Then, I drew the first circle and added more circles in a for loop.

```
library(purrr)
library(sf)

g <- st_sfc(c(st_point(1:2),st_point(3:2)))

purrr::map(.x = c(0.5, 1, 2),
           .f = function(x){st_buffer(g, x)}) -> foo

plot(st_geometry(foo[[1]]), xlim = c(0, 4), ylim = c(0, 4))

for(i in 2:length(foo)) {plot(st_geometry(foo[[i]]), add = TRUE)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your request (using a loop) see here an example

```
library(sf)
g = st_sfc(c(st_point(1:2),st_point(3:2)))
#Buffers
buffers=c(2,1,0.5)
#Initialise result
result=g
#Loop
for (i in buffers){
  #Appending buffered points
  result=c(result,st_buffer(g,i))
}
#Remove initial element
result=result[-1]
plot(result, axes=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), I made the following based mainly on [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr), relying on `map*`functions. In this case, the plots are made with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), and generates three plots in `gg` object.

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

g <- st_sfc(c(st_point(1:2),st_point(3:2)))

buffers <- c(0.5, 1, 2)

x <- map2(buffers, g, function(buf, points){

  points %>% 
    st_buffer(., buf)

}) %>% 
  set_names(., nm = sprintf("g.%s", buffers))

gg <- map(names(x), function(y){
  z <- x[[y]]

  z %>% 
    ggplot(.) + 
    geom_sf() + 
    labs(title = y)

})
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>